# how to find employee in netsuite via name using the RestAPI

Tags: java, rest, netsuite

I am trying to integrate the netsuite using RestAPI. But when trying to fetch employee record i am not able to get a response. The API keeps giving me the following error.

```
{
 "title": "Bad Request",
 "status": 400,
 "o:errorDetails": [
    "detail": "Invalid search query. Detailed unprocessed description follows. Search error occurred: Record 'employee' was not found.",
    "o:errorQueryParam": "q",
    "o:errorCode": "INVALID_PARAMETER"
    ]
}
```

I am able to get other records and fields but not employee. URL I am using: **https://12345.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/employee**

Comment: You've got to add query params to your url: https://12345.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/employee?q=empNum==101 (I made up empNum)

Comment: tried multiple combination of it. Like "/record/v1/employee?q=entityid IS 3031" and "/record/v1/employee?q=entityid=3031" but nothing worked. always get "Invalid search query. Provide a valid search query" error

Comment: Do you have the API specification link where I can look for its documentation?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1545141500.html This is the official documentation URL. but i have checked in the documentation and I have tried the approach given in the documentation.

Comment: facing the same problem, have you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

https://youracc.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/employee

to use that api you must send a "GET" request with a JSON body like this:

```
{}
```

[image: POSTMAN example]

Your role must have access to employees to see this